# GPO not applied to Windows 7 and higher

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-domain

There are two domain controllers. The primary works on the Windows Server 2008 R2 and the secondary on Windows Server 2012.

When I create a GPO on the primary controller, it is immediately copied to the secondary domain controller with all files and scripts.

In the GPO in the User Configuration section, I set system environment variables, as well as creating a folder on desktop and shortcuts in it.

GPO scope security filtering contains group of users, which is in the Users folder of the domain controller. Members entering into it are located in different organizational units.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBZez.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTIIP.png]

If I logged on computers running Windows XP SP3, the policy execute immediately or after running `gpupdate /force`. On computers with an operating system version Windows 7 and higher (Windows 8.1, Windows 10) - the policy does not work out, and does not apply to the user.

In `gpresult /scope user /z > c:\gpo_dump.log` I see that User is member of needed group, but not found GPO in applied GPOs section and in not accepted GPOs section. Why? Execute `gpupdate /force` and some times reboot not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the date of your question I believe I know the answer to your problem.

There has been MS Security update released on 14/6/2016 which changed behaviour of GPOs with user settings! A lot

Up until now all GPOs with any user settings were applied under user security context. Therefore, policies got applied as long as the user was listed in the security filtering (as you have it).

But with the behaviour after the MS update they get applied under the computer context. So, if you have a user or a group in the security filtering it's not enough for the user settings in the policy to get applied. You also need to have **read permission** for the computer from which the user accesses the GPO from. You dont have to list it in security filtering but you have to add at least READ permission (on the GPO delegation tab) to the computer or a group which this computer is member of.

So basically, if userA is connecting from computerB, you will have the userA listed in the security filtering and the computerB needs to have READ permission on the GPO (not the apply policy permission).
See this link [Deploy MS16-072](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2016/06/22/deploying-group-policy-security-update-ms16-072-kb3163622/) which explains everything and also offers script to repair the affected GPOs. MS suggest to add READ permission for Authenticated Users to all GPOs (thats what the script they provide is for) but I think Domain Computers is little safer.

This has been bugging me for weeks. I could not work out why some GPOs suddenly stopped working. It's all because of this. I would appreciate if such a massive change had more publicity because I was running totaly insecure environment for really long time because non of restrictive GPOs was getting applied. I know I should but I dont really read about all the MS Updates I am applying. I hope this helps your case.

Here is the script to add Authenticated users read permissions to all GPOs which have no permission for Authenticated users.

```
    # Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

$osver = [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version
$win7 = New-Object System.Version 6, 1, 7601, 0

if($osver -lt $win7)
{
    Write-Error "OS Version is not compatible for this script. Please run on Windows 7 or above"
    return
}

Try
{
    Import-Module GroupPolicy
}
Catch
{
    Write-Error "GP Management tools may not be installed on this machine. Script cannot run"
    return
}

$arrgpo = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($loopGPO in Get-GPO -All)
{
    if ($loopGPO.User.Enabled)
    {
        $AuthPermissionsExists = Get-GPPermissions -Guid $loopGPO.Id -All | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Trustee | ? {$_.Name -eq "Authenticated Users"}
        If (!$AuthPermissionsExists)
        {
            $arrgpo.Add($loopGPO) | Out-Null
        }
    }
}

if($arrgpo.Count -eq 0)
{
    echo "All Group Policy Objects grant access to 'Authenticated Users'"
    return
}
else
{
    Write-Warning  "The following Group Policy Objects do not grant any permissions to the 'Authenticated Users' group:"
    foreach ($loopGPO in $arrgpo)
    {
        write-host "'$($loopgpo.DisplayName)'"
    }
}

$title = "Adjust GPO Permissions"
$message = "The Group Policy Objects (GPOs) listed above do not have the Authenticated Users group added with any permissions. Group policies may fail to apply if the computer attempting to list the GPOs required to download does not have Read Permissions. Would you like to adjust the GPO permissions by adding Authenticated Users group Read permissions?"

$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", `
    "Adds Authenticated Users group to all user GPOs which don't have 'Read' permissions"
$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", `
    "No Action will be taken. Some Group Policies may fail to apply"
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)  
$appliedgroup = $null
switch ($result)
{
    0 {$appliedgroup = "Authenticated Users"}
    1 {$appliedgroup = $null}
}
If($appliedgroup)
{
    foreach($loopgpo in $arrgpo)
    {
        write-host "Adding 'Read' permissions for '$appliedgroup' to the GPO '$($loopgpo.DisplayName)'."
        Set-GPPermissions -Guid $loopgpo.Id -TargetName $appliedgroup -TargetType group -PermissionLevel GpoRead | Out-Null
    }
}
```

If you preffer to set the read permission for Domain Computers rather than Auth. Users just change this `0 {$appliedgroup = "Authenticated Users"}` to that `0 {$appliedgroup = "Domain Computers"}`

Adding for clarification:

Whichever computer, user or a group to which you wish to APPLY the GPO settings needs to be listed in the security filtering. Listing computer user or a group in the security filtering effectively means, that you are giving the computer, user or a group two permissions over the GPO - one permission is READ and the other is APPLY THE GROUP POLICY. The delegation tab is giving you option to assign permissions to the GPO in more detail but you can check that if you add computer, user or a group in the security filtering tab it will appear on the delegation tab with these two permissions READ and APPLY.

By adding computer, user or a group to a delegation tab and giving it READ permission you ARE NOT applying the GPO to it. You are just allowing it to read the GPO.

So lets summarize -

- for a GPO COMPUTER SETTINGS to get applied you need to have the computer (or a group it is in) listed in the security filtering.
- For a GPO USER SETTINGS to get applied you need to have the user (or
  a group it is in) listed in the security filtering AND you need to
  give the computer (or a group it is in) from which the user access
  the GPO a READ permission on the GPO.

I hope this clarifies it for you.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, I tried to create a policy that creates the environment variables - one in the computer section, the other in the user section. Added to the user's security domain filter, and the delegation has given permission to read the domain computers. Has not added any computer in the security filter - computer section does not apply at all.

Comment: That's not how it (works. You have to have the computer to which you want to apply the computer settings) in the security filtering. Let me elaborate in a moment

Comment: I added explanation to the end of my answer. THat should clarify it